# Jquerymobile panel after postback dissappear

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mobile, postback, panel

I have a usercontrol(asp.net) inside a jquerymobile panel. This usercontrol is a normal contactus form with a submit button. I have some back-end error validation. So after the postback, I want to show those errors. My issue is that jquerymobile panel gets hidden after the post back and when you click the show button only then it display the error messages and the form. I want a way so that it keeps the panel open until the user click the close button in panel(I have that button in panel and works fine).

Would you please guide me how to get that functionality?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions which seems quite applicable to your problem:

1. You can use javascript/ajax for your backend validation and show errors as response.
2. You may want to try iframes in your panel, what you can do is keep you form in an iframe, so that when you submit the form only iframe contents will reload not the whole of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. I thought of using ajax for that purpose but since its a web form, and may require few postbacks(incase of validation) I left that option. I think If I have to use such functionality I would use ajax. Thanks again manish.